# Facebook javascript SDK post with properties

Tags: javascript, facebook

Using a "Poll" app on Facebook, it would post something like this to my facebook Page (Kid Task):[image]

How can I do this using Facebook javascript SDK? As best as I can tell, this allows it https://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/attachments/ but this says "for REST API" and that is deprecated right?

Code i've tried:

```
        FB.api(
        'https://graph.facebook.com/kidtask/feed/',
        'post',
        {
            message: 'test question',
            actions: { name: 'Vote Now', link: 'http://test.com' },
            properties: { text: "test answer 1", href: "http://test.com" }
        },
        function(response) {
            if (!response) {
                alert('Error occurred.');
            } else if (response.error) {
                document.getElementById('result').innerHTML =
                    'Error: ' + response.error.message;
            } else {
                document.getElementById('result').innerHTML =
                    '<a href=\"https://www.facebook.com/kidtask/' +
                        response.id + '\">' +
                        'Story created.  ID is ' +
                        response.id + '</a>';
            }
        }
    );
```

This posts without errors, but the properties are ignored.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out finally, although i'm not sure what it was exactly. My guess is, I was trying to post as a text post and not a link post.

```
    FB.api(
        '/kidtask/feed/',
        'post',
        {
            name: 'whatever',
            link: 'http://url',
            actions: { name: 'Vote Now', link: 'http://url' },
            description:"\u003Cbr/\u003E",
            picture:"http://imageurl",
            caption:"\u003Cbr/\u003E",
            properties: [{"text":"test 1","href":"http://url"},{"text":"test 2","href":"http://url"},{"text":"test 3","href":"http://url"}]
        },
```